# Problemas ao recuperar dado via JPA alterado diretamente na entidade relacionada

Tags: jpa

Tenho a seguinte entidade

```
@Entity
@Table(name="matricula")
public class Matricula implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", nullable = false)
    private Usuario usuario;

    //...
}
```

A entidade Matricula pertence a um aluno (usuario) e somente um aluno.
Porem estou com um problema. Quando busco a matricula apos alterar o dado diretamento no aluno, embora no banco de dados a informação já esteja atualizada. 
na rotina ainda vem o dado antigo.

Entidade usuario.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="tipo_do_cartao")
    private TipoDeCartao cartao;
    //---
}
```

Persistencia de alteração do usuario.

```
// Methodos.
public String confirma(){
    if(novoTipoDeCartao == null || novoTipoDeCartao.equals(usuario.getCartao()) ){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("O novo tipo de cartão não pode ser nulo ou não pode ser igual ao atual");
        return "";
    }
    try{
        usuario.setCartao(novoTipoDeCartao);
        servicoUsuario.trocarTipoDeCartao(usuario);
        return "/Index.xhtml";
    } catch (NegocioException e){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}

@Transacao
    public void trocarTipoDeCartao(Usuario usuario) {
        Matricula matriculaAtiva = servicoMatricula.matriculaAtiva(usuario.getId());
        servicoDocumento.cancelaDocumentos(matriculaAtiva,EstadoDoDocumento.VENCIDO_TROCA);
        usuario = usuarioDao.salvar(usuario);
        matriculaAtiva = servicoMatricula.matriculaAtiva(usuario.getId());
    }

public Usuario salvar(Usuario usuario) {
        System.out.println("-- UsuarioDao salvar-----");
        try {
            usuario = entityManager.merge(usuario);
            //entityManager.flush();
            return usuario;
        }catch (PersistenceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //throw new NegocioException("Email já cadastrado");
            throw new NegocioException(TrataErro.buscaErro(e,"Não foi possivel salvar"));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //throw new NegocioException("Email já cadastrado");
            throw new NegocioException(TrataErro.buscaErro(e,"Não foi possivel salvar (E)"));
        }   
    }
```

Buscar a matricula

```
public Matricula matriculaAtiva(Long usuarioId) {
        return matriculaDao.buscarMatriculaAtiva(usuarioId);
    }

public Matricula buscarMatriculaAtiva(Long idUsuarioLogado) {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Matricula> cq = cb.createQuery(Matricula.class);
            Root<Matricula> m = cq.from(Matricula.class);
            cq.select(m);
            List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

            criteria.add(cb.equal(m.<Long>get("usuario").get("id"),idUsuarioLogado));
            criteria.add(cb.equal(m.<Boolean>get("status"),true));

            cq.where(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            cq.orderBy(cb.asc(m.get("id")));
            TypedQuery<Matricula> tq = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

            Matricula mat = tq.getSingleResult();
            return mat;

        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: O select ocorre depois do commit? Se for salvar os dados e quiser ter o objeto atualizado, devera fazer o flush.

Comment: Sim. O Select ocorre após o commit.

Comment: mas no caso é na mesma request ou em outra? usa algum tipo de cache?
como estão seus scopos na view? pergunto isso porque você pode estar com o objeto na session e apresentando sim um objeto desatualizado.

Comment: É uma outra request. Todas a minhas telas com viewscope. O que é estranho é que se na tela que chama o cadastro  mostro o campo em questão (mesmo com disable=false), mostra atualizado e na tela de cadastro vem atualizado. Senão, a primeira vez que entro vem desatualizada. Se fechar e chamar novamente vem correto. Esta muito estranho. Fiz a gambiarra de mostrar o valor na tela anterior, ao menos no momento esta funcionando, mas não gostei desta solução.